# $\Bbb R^2$ is not equal to $span(a,b)$ for any $(a,b)\in \Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

As $(1 ,0)$ belong to span of $(1, 1)$ but $\Bbb R^2$ is not equal to $span(1 ,1) ?$

Comment: $\operatorname{span} \{(1,1)\} = \{ (a,a) \mid a \in \mathbb R\}$

Comment: $(1,0)$ does NOT belong to the span of $(1,1)$.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is? I *think* you are asking to prove that R^2 can not be the span of any single vector (a,b). Is that correct?

Comment: Note @Andrews's comment tells us the span of $(1, 1)$ is the line $y = x$ in $\mathbb R^2$, but one line does not span all of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Yeah my question is why R^2 can not be span of any single vector (a b). How can i you prove this statement ? @Victoria

Comment: See the answer below from Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the span of $(a,b)$ can only contain $(1,0)$ if $b = 0$.  It can only contain $(0,1)$ if $a = 0$.  But clearly, if $a = b = 0$, then the span of $(a,b)$ is just $\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Sir then how you prove that R^2 can not be span of every single vector  (a b)?

Answer (score 0):

It is easily shown that the span of a vector is its corresponding line.